# Why did the Cia cia tribe in Indonesia choose 한 글 for the alphabet?

Tags: hangul

I heard that this tribe does not have alphabets to write. But instead using ABC, why they using 한 글?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, they don't use Korean characters (any more).  It was a misguided attempt by a group of Korean activists, which eventually fizzled out, as far as I know.

https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%B0%8C%EC%95%84%EC%B0%8C%EC%95%84%EC%96%B4

https://namu.wiki/w/%EC%B0%8C%EC%95%84%EC%B0%8C%EC%95%84%EC%96%B4

Comment: Oh, it's because of there is a group of people make an attempt to spread the influence (it's look like that).

Comment: But, recently I watch a TV program talking about this tribe, so I thought they still use the characters.

Comment: I thought it is because there is something special about  한 글 or it is actually easy compare to A B C. The thing is, even the country itself  use A B C.

Comment: There was a statement that it was part of the Basic Law of Indonesia, that all tribal languages had to be written in Roman script. I haven't been able to verify that independently, but it doesn't sound inconsistent with the ethnic tensions that have existed in that nation.

Answer (score 1):

While it's unfortunate that the plan did not follow through, the logic for using 한글 over the Roman alphabet can be as follows:
1) more exact phonetics compared to the Roman alphabet. 한글 has a (more or less) 1:1 correlation between character and pronunciation, as opposed to the multiple possibilities of the Roman alphabet (Ex: 'A' can be a long 'A' as in 'Ant' but also a short 'A' as in 'Apple')
2) easy to learn. The Hangeul follows a visual mapping of the mouth that linguists have lauded as scientific and logical.
3) Hangeul is a syllable-based alphabet, meaning that it clearly depicts distinctions from one syllable to the next (i.e. each 'block' is a syllable, while in English it is impossible to tell from just the written form)

If for all these reasons Hangeul better suits the Cia cia tribe's language, it makes sense to choose it over the Roman alphabet. But of course, other factors could still weigh in on the decision, such as globalization, politics, etc.

Comment: 1. This is feature of the languages using the Roman alphabet, not the alphabets itself, there are languages with a 1:1 relation.